# sort function works only in mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, sorting, mozilla

i have a Problem with this sort function.
In mozilla it works fine, but when i try Chrome or IE it does nothing.
I hope someone can help.

I found something about operators for array.sort in mozilla 
https://allenpike.com/2009/arraysort-browser-differences
but it did not help

https://jsfiddle.net/dojpw86a/1/

html

```
<div class="sortcon">
  <button id="offerdown" onClick="$('#allbdcontainer .bdcontainer').sort(sortbyoffer).appendTo('#allbdcontainer')">
  sortofferup
  </button>
   <button id="offerup" onClick="$('#allbdcontainer .bdcontainer').sort(sortbyoffer).appendTo('#allbdcontainer')">
  sortofferdown
  </button>

<div id="allbdcontainer"> 

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">01.11.2018
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">31.12.2025
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P3
</div>

</div>

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">01.11.2018
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">31.12.2019
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P1D
</div>

</div>

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">15.10.2018
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">20.10.2018
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P2V
</div>

</div>

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">15.10.2018
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">28.10.2018
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P2V
</div>

</div>

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">07.08.2019
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">04.09.2019
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P1D
</div>

</div>

<div class="bdcontainer">

<div class="clear">
</div>

<div class="bdshowfromdate">22.03.2020
</div>

<div class="seperator">-
</div>

<div class="bdshowtodate">25.03.2020
</div>

<div class="bdshowoffer">P2I
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

function:

```
 function sortbyoffer(a, b) {
  if(event.target.id == 'offerup')
  {
      return $(a).find(".bdshowoffer").text() < $(b).find(".bdshowoffer").text();
  }
  else if(event.target.id == 'offerdown')
  {
    return $(a).find(".bdshowoffer").text() > $(b).find(".bdshowoffer").text();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer without the array, as @natiole asked for in a comment.

```js
function sortList(sortDirection) {
  let list = $('.bdcontainer')
  list.sort((a, b) => {
    if ($(a).find('.bdshowoffer').text() < $(b).find('.bdshowoffer').text()) {
      return -1 * sortDirection
    }
    if ($(a).find('.bdshowoffer').text() > $(b).find('.bdshowoffer').text()) {
      return 1 * sortDirection
    }
    return 0
  })
  return list
}

function renderList(list, container) {
  let htmlString = ''
  // jQuery .each()
  list.each((i, el) => {
    htmlString += $(el).prop('outerHTML')
  })
  container
    .empty()
    .append(htmlString)
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#offerdown').on('click', function(e) {
    renderList(sortList(1), $('#allbdcontainer'))
  })
  $('#offerup').on('click', function(e) {
    renderList(sortList(-1), $('#allbdcontainer'))
  })

})
```

```css
.bdshowfromdate,
.seperator,
.bdshowtodate,
.bdshowoffer {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 68px;
}

.bdcontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortcon">
  <button id="offerdown">
  sortofferup
  </button>
  <button id="offerup">
  sortofferdown
  </button>

  <div id="allbdcontainer">

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">01.11.2018
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">31.12.2025
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P3
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">01.11.2018
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">31.12.2019
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P1D
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">15.10.2018
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">20.10.2018
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P2V
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">15.10.2018
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">28.10.2018
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P2V
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">07.08.2019
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">04.09.2019
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P1D
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bdcontainer">

      <div class="clear">
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowfromdate">22.03.2020
      </div>

      <div class="seperator">-
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowtodate">25.03.2020
      </div>

      <div class="bdshowoffer">P2I
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

It's a correct solution, but I think the previous one is better (e.g. handling arrays in JS is faster, less dependent on jQuery, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your problem - although a bit modified.

The main point is that I created an array of objects that holds all the data of the table, and created the necessary functions for displaying that data.

I also added the toggle function, that's working together with the other ASC / DESC sorting.

```js
// adding toggle function
let toggleDirection = 1
// data array
let dataArray = [{
    bdshowfromdate: '01.11.2018',
    bdshowtodate: '31.12.2025',
    bdshowoffer: 'P3'
  },
  {
    bdshowfromdate: '01.11.2018',
    bdshowtodate: '31.12.2019',
    bdshowoffer: 'P1D'
  },
  {
    bdshowfromdate: '15.10.2018',
    bdshowtodate: '20.10.2018',
    bdshowoffer: 'P2V'
  },
  {
    bdshowfromdate: '15.10.2018',
    bdshowtodate: '28.10.2018',
    bdshowoffer: 'P2V'
  },
  {
    bdshowfromdate: '07.08.2019',
    bdshowtodate: '04.09.2019',
    bdshowoffer: 'P1D'
  },
  {
    bdshowfromdate: '22.03.2020',
    bdshowtodate: '25.03.2020',
    bdshowoffer: 'P2I'
  },
]

// generating the HTML to be displayed as the table
function tableHtml(tableData) {
  let ret = ''
  tableData.forEach(item => {
    ret += '<div class="bdcontainer">'
    ret += '<div class="clear"></div>'
    ret += `<div class="bdshowfromdate">${item.bdshowfromdate}</div>`
    ret += '<div class="seperator">-</div>'
    ret += `<div class="bdshowtodate">${item.bdshowtodate}</div>`
    ret += `<div class="bdshowoffer">${item.bdshowoffer}</div>`
    ret += '</div>'
  })
  return ret
}

// adding the generated HTML to the DOM
function refreshTable(tableData) {
  const htmlString = tableHtml(tableData)
  jQuery("#allbdcontainer")
    .empty()
    .append(htmlString)
}

// sorting function
function sortTable(tableData, sortDirection) {
  tableData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.bdshowoffer < b.bdshowoffer) {
      return -1 * sortDirection
    }
    if (a.bdshowoffer > b.bdshowoffer) {
      return 1 * sortDirection
    }
  })
  return tableData
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // initial display of data
  refreshTable(dataArray)

  $('#offerdown').on('click', function(e) {
    dataArray = sortTable(dataArray, 1)
    refreshTable(dataArray)
    toggleDirection = -1
  })
  $('#offerup').on('click', function(e) {
    dataArray = sortTable(dataArray, -1)
    refreshTable(dataArray)
    toggleDirection = 1
  })
  $('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    dataArray = sortTable(dataArray, toggleDirection)
    refreshTable(dataArray)
    toggleDirection = toggleDirection * -1
  })


})
```

```css
.bdshowfromdate,
.seperator,
.bdshowtodate,
.bdshowoffer {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 68px;
}

.bdcontainer {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortcon">
  <button id="offerdown">
  sortofferdown
  </button>
  <button id="offerup">
  sortofferup
  </button>
  <button id="toggle">
  toggleSorting
  </button>

  <div id="allbdcontainer"></div>
```

With this solution

- it is easier to change the table template
- it is easier to add new properties to the table
- it is easier to add sorting functions to different properties
- it is easier to handle data
- it scales better

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to do this without the array, because in my case the data of the table is created through php and i have no access to change this. I could get all the data with javascript from html, break and append everything to build the new table, but i dont think thats the best solution. I'm still curious why my function works on mozilla but not on Chrome and IE.

Comment: One problem was that you should've put that in **jQuery(document).ready()**, then you'll see an error message (something is not ok with the functions). I added another answer - without the array handling. But I still advise you to move in this direction - maybe you can alter the PHP to **echo** the JS array, or something.